# Are questions about web services on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

There have been several questions about web services and applications recently, and some have received close votes, so I think it'd be helpful to discuss whether these questions **are** on-topic for the site.

Some examples:

- [What happens after my Google business email expires?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/665/what-happens-after-my-google-business-email-expires)
- [What IoT services are available for storing/sending/publishing generic data in the cloud?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/600/what-iot-services-are-available-for-storing-sending-publishing-generic-data-in-t)
- [How delayed can IFTTT triggers be?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/503/how-delayed-can-ifttt-triggers-be)

So, are these questions on-topic, or should they be closed (and, in future, potentially migrated to [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) if it is clear that these questions **will not** be on-topic here)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would add this [question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/646/online-shopping)<sup><sup><sub>1</sub></sup></sup>
to the list of questions which in my mind are potentially mis-understanding the specific meaning of *Internet of Things*. Even without a specific, clear definition, we accept this term means something in the context of [smart-home](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-home), [smart-city](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-city), [smart-office](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-office), [smart-farm](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-farm), [smart-hospital](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-hospital).

My example, and the Google email question seem, to me, fairly clearly off topic. There is nothing in these questions to give them a specific IoT context, they are simple *things on the internet* questions.

Questions about IoT cloud services seem on-topic, particularly the ones detailed in [this answer](https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/613/99). Various providers have come and come in this space in the past few years, as opposed to the more generic rent-a-server cloud offerings. If we want expert answers, we need questions which appeal to low-level developers.

Questions about an application of IFTTT are not automatically off-topic, although I imagine some [ifttt](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ifttt) questions might be borderline depending on the subject. More likely, I'd expect [ifttt](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ifttt) could attract too-broad questions or no-research rather than off-topic.

---

<sub>1: Question is deleted and is only visible with 4k reputation.</sub>

Comment: Using IFTTT to link various web services to each other is probably off-topic; using IFTTT to link hardware gadgets to web services is likely on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

This is a poorly stated question, as it imagines a category of "web services" that is entirely orthogonal to anything which matters for fitting into this this site - and groups three entirely distinct things for common attention, which they are simply too different to receive.

- Rather obviously the google business email question is **blatantly off topic**.
- "What IoT services are available for storing/sending/publishing generic data in the cloud?" is a site-related area, but pretty much all Stack Exchange sites reject as too broad questions which seek a list of what is out there - **Stack Exchange sites are for questions that can have a *specific* answer, not for making lists**.
- "How delayed can IFTTT triggers be?"  This seems like an IoT question, and at least from the title an appropriate one (though as in the previous go-around, not all IFTTT questions will be device related)

The diversity of answers for the three examples should demonstrate why it's hazardous to encourage thinking in terms of inapplicable categories - what matters not is if these are "web services", what matters is if they are **about IoT** and additionally if they are **questions fitting the Stack Exchange model**.